# Как поменять местами максимальный элемент и A[1,1] ? (алгоритм решения или код если несложно, только отдельно от основного)

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, delphi, замена

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // очистка
  Memo1.Clear;

  for i := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount - 1 do
    StringGrid1.Cols[i].Clear;

  // создание матрицы/таблицы
  if not TryStrToInt(Edit1.Text, n) then
    exit;

  if n < 2 then
    exit;

  SetLength(a, n, n);
  StringGrid1.RowCount := n;
  StringGrid1.ColCount := n;
  Randomize;
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    for j := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      a[i, j] := random(511) - 255;
      StringGrid1.Cells[j, i] := IntToStr(a[i, j]);
    end;

  // определения максимального элемента
  max := a[0, 0];
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    for j := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if a[i, j] > max then
        max := a[i, j];
    end;

  // нахождение адресов максимального элемента
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Максимальный элемент = ' + IntToStr(max));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Его адреса:');
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    for j := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if a[i, j] = max then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Строка ' + IntToStr(i) + ', столбец ' + IntToStr(j));
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Чтобы поменять местами два значения, используйте промежуточную переменную. И запоминать надо не максимальное значение, а его "адрес" (значения индексов).

Comment: Попытки были, применение переменной buf. (buf:=a[i,j]; a[i,j]:=a[1,1]; a[1,1]:=buf;) Программа не дает сбой, но и нужного эффекта от нее нет:/

Answer (score 0):

При нахождении максимума запоминайте его индексы

```
imax := 0;
jmax := 0;
...

if a[i,j] > max then begin
    max := a[i,j];
    imax := i;
    jmax := j;
end;
```

И обратите внимание, что слегка отформатированный код легче читать

В попытке обмена используется `[1,1]`, а поиск ведется, начиная с нулевых индексов. Как надо-то?